# copy linked files in visual studio to a location

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a project set up in my visual studio solution that contains a number of linked files. These are content files.

When I build the project I would like to copy the linked files to another location. Is this possible and how can I achieve it?

Comment: Are these 'linked files' to be copied to a location that is completely separate from the website? (I'm assuming from the asp.net question tag, you're building a website).

Comment: yes correct. They are to be copied a separate location on the same file system.

Answer (score 16):

For anybody stumbling on this page like myself, further to 5arx' post, I implemented an MSBuild target that copies all linked content files to their "virtual" locations (the directory where you placed the link in Visual Studio):
http://mattperdeck.com/post/Copying-linked-content-files-at-each-build-using-MSBuild.aspx

Comment: This was spot on! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have had to rely on a different technique.  For years, I have been using [@user1147862's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16473185/1006269) for years, but with Visual Studio 2022 / .NET 6, it doesn't work at all.  Visual Studio no longer appears to "see" any content files added as links and the Copy essentially does nothing.

So here is what I do now.  In my case, I have a bunch of JS files that I include into multiple projects under wwwroot/common/js.  I add the following to my CSPROJ file...

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Adds the files as links in the Solution Explorer.
       When you double-click, it opens the original file. -->
  <Content Include="..\..\Common\**\*.js">
    <Link>wwwroot\Common\%(RecursiveDir)%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
  </Content>

   <!-- Picked up by the Copy below.  Using "Content"
        with "Link" adds external files as links.  But a custom
        name is needed for use with Copy. -->
  <CommonJs Include="..\..\Common\**\*.js" />

  <!-- Tells Visual Studio to ignore any actual files at this location.
       I found that if I didn't do this, Visual Studio sees the copied
       file instead of the linked file.  This tells Visual Studio to
       ignore the copied file so that when I double-click it in
       Solution Explorer, it opens the original copy. -->
  <Content Remove="wwwroot\Common\**" />
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="CopyCommonJs" BeforeTargets="Build">
  <Copy SourceFiles="@(CommonJs)"
        DestinationFiles="wwwroot\Common\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)"
        SkipUnchangedFiles="true"
        OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="true" />
</Target>
```

The whole approach works and I understand all the parts now, but I prefer the old way and wish it still worked.  If someone finds something more elegant, please let me know.

Comment: Where does this live? Do you put this in the project that contains all the common js files or do you put this in all the projects that have links?

Comment: @DonnyV., these lines go in web project that is referencing the common JS files, i.e. the projects that would have had links.  This technique replaces the linked files technique.

Answer (score 1):

if you right click on the project, then choose the "Build Events" tab, you should be able to create a post build event script which will take any file you specify and copy it to the location you specify.

Good place to start would be [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for this but as the files are linked files, they dont exist within in the project on the file system. How could I handle this?

Comment: You should still be able to target them using XCOPY - essentially, the post build commands are stored in a .bat file which the environment executes after you have built the project. If the files themselves aren't going to be moved and you can rely on absolute paths to them, use the absolute paths in the build events script and move them on out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [MSBuild](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd). Specifically with its [Copy Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx) task:

Answer (score 0):

It seems that simply adding

```
<CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
```

to the linked file item in a Visual Studio 2017 csproj project file will cause the linked file to be copied to the output directory on build, whether you have declared the build action as None or Content.

For example these both work...

```
<None Include="..\configuration\Shared.OctopusDeploy.config">
  <Link>Shared.OctopusDeploy.config</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>

<Content Include="..\configuration\Shared.OctopusDeploy.config">
  <Link>Shared.OctopusDeploy.config</Link>
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Content>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I believe this doesn't work anymore with VS2022 / SDK-format projects